# Difference between values in two SQL queries

Tags: sql-server, difference

I have a problem getting the actual difference between values from two different sql queries. For eg:

- Query 1:

  ```
  SELECT x from db1 where date = 'mm-dd-yy'
  ```
- Query 2:

  ```
  SELECT x from db1 where date = 'mm1-dd1-yy'
  ```

Each query returns 10 different values. I want a query that returns the actual difference between values in both queries( Value1 from Q1 - Value1 from Q2, similarly for value2 and so on) Tried EXCEPT but that doesnt work. Any suggestions?

Comment: First, such queries would only give correct results by chance. When it is a date or datetime do NOT use formats like mm-dd-yy. Use the canonical yyyyMMdd format if you have to use a string. Otherwise you can't trust the results.

Unfortunately I am not giving any sample for your query because it is not clear what you want to query. Would you please give some sample data and what you expect to get as a result?

Comment: I solved the query @CetinBasoz. Posted the answer below :) thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.x1- B.x2 AS Difference FROM

(

(SELECT c, x1 from db1 where date = 'mm-dd-yy') AS A

JOIN

(SELECT c, x2 from db1 where date = 'mm1-dd1-yy') AS B

ON B.c = A.c

ORDER BY A.c, B.c
```

Comment: As I said above, this kind of query depends on chance to give correct results. Do not use mm-dd-yy style. Use only ODBC canonical format when you need to use a string (yyyyMMdd).

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
Select  x-x2 from
(
(SELECT c1,(case when date = 'mm1-dd1-yy' then c11 end)as x2,x from kdue)
)as y
where date = 'mm1-dd1-yy'
```

Comment: Tried that. It says " Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. "

Comment: oh then let me edit it a bit i think i know whats causing that.

Comment: btw do you have any id in your table?

Comment: No. I dont have any id. My table returns a value based on a condition, thats it

Comment: I mean in your table structure (db1) not in your query

Comment: Yes it has an id which is a PK

Comment: Sorry for the delay got distracted by some stuff, but i think i fixed it, hope that works.

Comment: That returns a bunch of nulls somehow :(

Comment: whaaa, welp ill do more tests then.

Comment: "value 1 from q1 and value 2 from q2 " how do u knw which is val 1 are u using any order by or any sort of sequence?

Comment: They are sorted alphabetically based on another column which is included in both the tables.

Comment: @ivan In your query both dates seem to be the same but in my requirement both are different. Also that isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly can you please see below approach if it works for you.

```
select value1_From_QRY1-value1_From_QRY2 from (
   select row_cnt,sum(val1) as value1_From_QRY1,sum(va2) as value1_From_QRY2 from 
    (SELECT ROWNUM as row_cnt,x as val1 ,0 as val2 from db1 where date = 'mm-dd-yy' 
     union all
    SELECT ,ROWNUM ,0,x from db1 where date = 'mm1-dd1-yy')
   group by row_cnt)
```